# Fractional Edge Coloring of Snarks

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

A [snark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_%28graph_theory%29) is a graph that is connected, regular of degree 3, bridgeless, but has edge chromatic number 4. The fractional edge chromatic number is therefore between 3 and 4. I have checked several and all cases have fractional edge chromatic number 3. So: Is it the case that all snarks have fractional edge chromatic number 3?

Stan Wagon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\chi_f(G)$ = $\max (\Delta (G), \Lambda (G))$,  where $\Lambda (G)$ = $\max_H \frac{2\epsilon(H)}{\nu(H) − 1}$
where the maximization is over all induced subgraphs $H$ with $\nu(H) ≥ 3$ and odd. For Snarks, $\Lambda (G) \leq 3$. For more details check the chapter on edge coloring in [Fractional  Graph Theory.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471178640)

Comment: Excellent. Many thanks.